# Does DisplayAttribute encourage bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm struggling to find real world value in annotating my view models with `DisplayAttribute`. The only advantage I can see is that this weakly typed view code:

`<label for="IPAddress">IP address</label>`

Becomes strongly typed:

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IPAddress)`

The disadvantage is that I need to recompile and redeploy my web app to fix a simple typo.

Wouldn't it be better to keep display-only information where it belongs, in the view, and have some sort of HTML helper to render the correct field ID, like this:

`<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.IPAddress)">IP address</label>`

I guess I'm just curious as to why the MVC guys went for the attribute-based solution. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: I went through the same phase too, I just use the overloaded html helpers to passs in what I need however you can write your views how you want, you can use the default options provided as you noted above or do it another way. Also if your content is 100% ajax driven, all you send is json data to the view and work it with jquery or another client side language- I think that may even be the norm very soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe DisplayAttributes support localization. This could be a good reason not to hard-code English labels...

This blog post may be of interest: 
[Localize ASPNET MVC 2 DataAnnontations](http://carrarini.blogspot.com/2010/08/localize-aspnet-mvc-2-dataannotations.html)

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered globalisation. This can also be achieved by localising the views (e.g. `Index.de.cshtml`) but it's certainly another feather in `DisplayAttribute`'s cap.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use your entities in a simple web app supporting one language I see no reason to use `LabelFor`.

Comment: Did you mean `I see no reason **not** to use LabelFor`?

Comment: No I meant that there are no reason to use it. Then again, there are no reasons to not use it either. It's just syntax preference when having only one language. `LabelFor` is great when doing localizations.

Comment: I thought you were referring to the `LabelFor` overload which takes as second argument the text to be displayed and thus avoid using the `DisplayAttribute` on the model.